# I am getting a weird popup FONDUE.exe. The image is in the link. Should I be worried?

Tags: windows-10, virus

[image: https://imgur.com/a/y3nguQj]

This was one of the only files not scanned because it was password protected

C:\ProgramData\Norton{DE658DFA-EF45-4457-907D-5DC71B6342C7}\profiles.dat=>1320.js

I ran SFC /scannow The error I found was " Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag. "

Here is my CBS.log. https://pastebin.com/5AkmE6vW

I am also currently running in powershell Repair-WindowsImage -Online -RestoreHealth

I found how to do this from this from https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/fondue-exe-constantly-popping-up.3747991/.

Anything else I need to do?

I also ran a virus scan from malwarebytes and bitdefender and didn't get any viruses.

Thanks.

Comment: Not anything on my Windows 10 or 11 machines. Run a full scan with Windows Defender including an Offline scan.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fondue

Comment: The file is legitimate. As to what might be causing it to be launched. That’s likely due to the system corruption that DISM and SFC has detected. Since this tool is only on Windows Server, what version, are you running? This tool would be launched if a optional feature was enabled, say WSL2, but due to systems corruption was no longer present and was in an unspecified state

Comment: Run also `chkdsk` - you seem to have some corruption in the file-system.

Comment: I ran chkdsk again and SFC /scannow in powershell. I also ran  a full scan with Windows Defender including an Offline scan. It seems all the scans are coming back witth no errors or viruse.  
Maybe this may unrelated but the windows key stopped working.
I am using windows 10 version 21H2( OS BUILD 19044.1586). 
 
@John

Comment: is your computer perhaps an MSI system running their Dragon Center software? I had a problem a few months ago where every morning my laptop would display the fondue syntax help, just like your image. I managed to track it to a scheduled task labeled "OneDC_Updater". disabling the task caused the message to stop appearing. appearently its using fondue to try to install a windows component, but has flubbed up the syntax, hence the usage/help popup

Comment: Yep it is. How do I disable it though?

Comment: in the start menu, search for and open `Task Scheduler`. look for a task called `OneDC_Updater`, right click the task, and select `Disable`. then just wait to see if the issue goes away.

Comment: "the windows key stopped working" - Sounds like you have software installed blocking the usage of the key.

Comment: @Frank Thomas

it seems to be working thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fondue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fondue) is a windows command-line utility used to enable/disable windows components and features.

The window you are seeing is called a [Usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Built-in_usage_help) message, and they are commonly displayed in a command shell when a command is entered improperly, perhaps due to missing or malformed arguments and options, and is intended to help the user use the command. In this case, fondue was invoked improperly by an executable running as a [Scheduled Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/about-the-task-scheduler), so it had no shell in which to display the error, and it was displayed to the desktop as a dialog window instead.

As we discussed, the message is being spawned by the [MSI Dragon Center](https://www.msi.com/Landing/dragon-center-download) update checker. Dragon Center uses a Scheduled Task to check for updates at user login, and then every day at 6AM (at least on my system). It appears to attempt to run Fondue but does so improperly.

Disabling the Scheduled Task should prevent the message from being displayed again, though in doing so, you are disabling automatic updates. You may want to reinstall the latest version of Dragon Center, and if the issue continues, consider reaching out to MSI support. This issue does not have much coverage on the Internet that I can find, so its likely they don't know its happening, or have opted not to risk creating more issues by widely distributing a fix.